# Generalize square roots using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-numbers

For curiosity reasons, I'm trying to see wether or not it is possible to define square roots of rational numbers using (maybe infinite) matrices, **without real numbers**, ie. using only integers or rational numbers. I'm guessing it is not possible, but I can't find any proof of this.

For example, one could define a number $n$ using two by two matrices, as $nI = \begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 \\
0 & n \\
\end{pmatrix}$

In which case, a square root candidate could be defined as $\sqrt{n} :=  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
n & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
because $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
n & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
n & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 \\
0 & n \\
\end{pmatrix} $

The problem with this definition is that $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{p} \neq \sqrt{np}$ :

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
n & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
p & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
p & 0 \\
0 & n \\
\end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
np & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $

I'm trying to find a working candidate respecting this condition as much as I'm trying to find a proof that it is not possible, but I find it hard to investigate matrices of higher, possibly infinite dimensions.

Comment: Assuming this would work this would be a square root of a matrix, not of the corresponding rational number.

Comment: @Peter as $\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}$ is not a complex number. But with this we would have a nice way to extend the rational numbers with square root numbers without resorting to real numbers.